# Why my buttons does not work?

Tags: javascript, html, chart.js

Hello I wrote this code in HTML using javascript and chart.js :

```js
var chart_labels = ['06:00', '09:00', '12:00', '15:00', '18:00', '21:00'];
var temp_dataset = ['1', '8', '10', '10', '9', '7'];
var rain_dataset = ['0', '0', '6', '32', '7', '2'];
var ctx = document.getElementById("forecast").getContext('2d');
var config = {
  type: 'bar',
  data: {
    labels: chart_labels,
    datasets: [{
      type: 'line',
      label: "Temperature (Celsius)",
      yAxisID: "y-axis-0",
      fill: false,
      data: temp_dataset,
    }, {
      type: 'bar',
      label: "Precipitation (%)",
      yAxisID: "y-axis-1",
      data: rain_dataset,
    }]
  },
  options: {
    scales: {
      yAxes: [{
        position: "left",
        "id": "y-axis-0",
      }, {
        position: "right",
        "id": "y-axis-1",
      }]
    }
  }
};
var forecast_chart = new Chart(ctx, config);
$("#0").click(function() {
  var data = forecast_chart.config.data;
  data.datasets[0].data = temp_dataset;
  data.datasets[1].data = rain_dataset;
  data.labels = chart_labels;
  forecast_chart.update();
});
$("#1").click(function() {
  var chart_labels = ['00:00', '03:00', '06:00', '09:00', '12:00', '15:00', '18:00', '21:00'];
  var temp_dataset = ['5', '3', '4', '8', '10', '11', '10', '9'];
  var rain_dataset = ['0', '0', '1', '4', '19', '19', '7', '2'];
  var data = forecast_chart.config.data;
  data.datasets[0].data = temp_dataset;
  data.datasets[1].data = rain_dataset;
  data.labels = chart_labels;
  forecast_chart.update();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Chart.js/2.5.0/Chart.min.js"></script>

<canvas id="forecast" width="300" height="150"></canvas>
<button id="0" type="button">Dataset 1</button>
<button id="1" type="button">Dataset 2</button>
```

But the problem is when I click on the button it has no effects... where is the problem according to you ? According to me, I define correctly my functions so it should be ok but it is not the case.

How can I solve this ?

Thank you !

Comment: Works perfectly fine for me, though you'll have to hide the embedded console to click the button

Comment: check if you are using `$(document).ready()` in your code like my answer.

Comment: this snippet is working fine for me.

Answer (score 1):

As you are using jquery selector to select the buttons your event handlers and the code for chart.js should be inside `$(document).ready()` .So it will work. Check the below code -

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
 var chart_labels = ['06:00', '09:00', '12:00', '15:00', '18:00', '21:00'];
var temp_dataset = ['1', '8', '10', '10', '9', '7'];
var rain_dataset = ['0', '0', '6', '32', '7', '2'];
var ctx = document.getElementById("forecast").getContext('2d');
var config = {
    type: 'bar',
    data: {
        labels: chart_labels,
        datasets: [{
            type: 'line',
            label: "Temperature (Celsius)",
            yAxisID: "y-axis-0",
            fill: false,
            data: temp_dataset,
        }, {
            type: 'bar',
            label: "Precipitation (%)",
            yAxisID: "y-axis-1",
            data: rain_dataset,
        }]
    },
    options: {
        scales: {
            yAxes: [{
                position: "left",
                "id": "y-axis-0",
            }, {
                position: "right",
                "id": "y-axis-1",
            }]
        }
    }
};
var forecast_chart = new Chart(ctx, config);
$("#0").click(function() {
    var data = forecast_chart.config.data;
    data.datasets[0].data = temp_dataset;
    data.datasets[1].data = rain_dataset;
    data.labels = chart_labels;
    forecast_chart.update();
});
$("#1").click(function() {
    var chart_labels = ['00:00', '03:00', '06:00', '09:00', '12:00', '15:00', '18:00', '21:00'];
    var temp_dataset = ['5', '3', '4', '8', '10', '11', '10', '9'];
    var rain_dataset = ['0', '0', '1', '4', '19', '19', '7', '2'];
    var data = forecast_chart.config.data;
    data.datasets[0].data = temp_dataset;
    data.datasets[1].data = rain_dataset;
    data.labels = chart_labels;
    forecast_chart.update();
});
});

</script>
```

Here is a working demo : https://jsfiddle.net/7t6vfdwf/2/

you can see the buttons are working to change the dataset on click.

Answer (score 0):

Your HTML IDs should start with a letter rather than a number

```
SyntaxError: '#1' is not a valid selector
```